# Nested while loops and how to access the inner one after first run

Tags: java, while-loop, nested

So I'm trying to make a menu with a sub-menu. So my first thought was a nested while loop. So I made a little program to try my idea and I was apparently wrong?

When I run this code

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;

        while(i != 2){
            i = Kbd.readInt("1 to go to inner 2 to exit");

            while(j != 2){
                j = Kbd.readInt("1 to continue 2 to exit to outer");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I can "access" the sub-menu and run infinite many times as I want until I exit (Which is if I press 2)
But after I start at the inner while loop's start I can't seem to access the inner loop again?

I would like to know if I'm thinking wrong or any suggestions on how I should do this.

(The Kbd class is our class' scanner)

Comment: Add `j = 1;` at the end of the outer loop.

Comment: I would move `int j = 1` one line above the second `while` loop – it puts that line of code closer to where it's used, which is generally good style, and also makes it more readable: define j, set it to 1, enter a loop using j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can't re-enter the inner loop, since j is always 2 when leaving the loop and is never changed outside.

Consider holding j locally with in the loop.

```
while (i != 2)
{
    int j = 1 ;
    while (j != 2)
        ...
}
```

After fixing this bug you will discover the next one. What happens if you press 2 in the 1st getInt()? Do you really want to enter the inner loop, no matter what value of i? The user prompt suggests something different.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that quite easily after I fixed this :)